# Socket.io not responding, Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io, localhost, backend

I'm moving my code to a server. This code works and renders database information perfectly on my own server I set up on localhost, however an error from index.html stating "io is not defined" displays when I run the code from my server. For whatever reason socket.io is not being recognized. Also, nothing is shown if I type in localhost:3000 in my browser. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have two files, server.js and index.html.

server.js:

```
    var mysql = require('mysql')
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000)
    var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1', // Important to connect to localhost after connecting via ssh in screen
    user: 'username',
    password: '12345',
    database: '12345',
    port: 3306
})


// Log any errors connected to the db
db.connect(function(err){
    if (err) console.log(err)
})


// Define/initialize our global vars
var notes = []
var isInitNotes = false
var socketCount = 0



//Socket.io code below

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    // Socket has connected, increase socket count
    socketCount++
    // Let all sockets know how many are connected

    io.sockets.emit('users connected', socketCount)

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        // Decrease the socket count on a disconnect, emit
        socketCount--
        io.sockets.emit('users connected', socketCount)
    })
    socket.on('new note', function(data){

        // New note added, push to all sockets and insert into db
        notes.push(data)
        io.sockets.emit('new note', data)
        // Use node's db injection format to filter incoming data
        db.query('INSERT INTO notes (note) VALUES (?)', data.note)
    })
 console.log("10");

    // Check to see if initial query/notes are set
    if (! isInitNotes) {
        // Initial app start, run db query
        db.query('SELECT * FROM `Users`')
            .on('result', function(data){
                // Push results onto the notes array
                //console.log(notes);
                notes.push(data)
            })
            .on('end', function(){
                // Only emit notes after query has been completed
                socket.emit('initial notes', notes)
            })

        isInitNotes = true
    } else {
        // Initial notes already exist, send out
        socket.emit('initial notes', notes)
    }

})
```

index.html: (thinking the problem is in either the way I'm linking my socket.io.js file, or in the line of code where I declare the variable "socket")

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Script below works with my server I set up on local host
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>-->

    <!-- script below properly links to the socket.io.js file in my directory, and throws no errors-->
    <script type= "node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000'); //LINE OF CODE IN QUESTION




        //Code below not really relevant to problem, but still part of my project.

        socket.on('initial notes', function(data){
            var html = ''
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                // We store html as a var then add to DOM after for efficiency
                html += '<li>' + data[i].Name + '</li>'
            }
            $('#notes').html(html)
        })

        // New note emitted, add it to our list of current notes
        socket.on('new note', function(data){
            $('#notes').append('<li>' + data.Name + '</li>')
        })

        // New socket connected, display new count on page
        socket.on('users connected', function(data){
            $('#usersConnected').html('Users connected: ' + data)
        })

        // Add a new (random) note, emit to server to let others know
        $('#newNote').click(function(){
            var newNote = 'This is a random ' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1)  + ' note'
            socket.emit('new note', {note: newNote})
        })
    })
    </script>
    <ul id="notes"></ul>
    <div id="usersConnected"></div>
    <div id="newNote">Create a new note:</div
```

SOLVED!

Figured it out. I used "script src="my servers ip address:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js" and then change the variable socket to var socket = io.connect('Servers ip address:3000'); So the answer was to take out localhost all together.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there could be a problem loading Socket.io from your server if it works locally (perhaps a permissions issue?), try loading it from Socket.io CDN to test.

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that exact link before, and unfortunately it threw an error. I've explored all of the options for linking to socket.io I could find on this site. Do you see anything wrong with the way I'm using localhost to declare that socket variable in my index.html file?

Comment: Why would you try "script src="localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js" ? In port 3000 you have Socket.io listening, not your server, unless you have Socket.io and your server listening on the same port (they shouldn't), could this be the problem?

Comment: Perhaps, I commented out that link because it worked on my local server I set up, but when I moved my files to an actual server, that link threw an error. The only solution to properly link to my socket.io.js file I've found is to link directly to where the its located in the directory (which is the link I left uncommented). Should I not be using port 3000 in the declaration of the variable "socket" in index.html? Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you say that was working locally then that shouldn't be the problem, you can try ```var socket = new io.Socket("127.0.0.1", {port:3000});
socket.connect();``` to try, perhaps "localhost" on your server it's not properly configured. Use the ip.

Comment: Figured it out. I used "script src="my servers ip address:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js" and then change the var socket to      var socket = io.connect('Servers ip address:3000'); So the answer was to take out localhost all together. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Seems like "localhost" is not configured in your server, glad i could help, best.